# Compare two lists and find the mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, list

I am having 2 lists:

```
List<DefectPopulation> lst_codeDefectSrc = new List<DefectPopulation>();
List<DefectPopulation> lst_codeDefectDest = new List<DefectPopulation>();
```

which are of type

```
private class DefectPopulation
{
    public int ClassCode { get; set; }
    public int DefectCount { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to compare the two lists and find the mismatching item.

In the below if condition, it is saying mismatch is found but I want to know where it is:

```cs
List<DefectPopulation> lst_codeDefectSrc = new List<DefectPopulation>();
List<DefectPopulation> lst_codeDefectDest = new List<DefectPopulation>();

private class DefectPopulation
{
    public int ClassCode { get; set; }
    public int DefectCount { get; set; }
}

List<DefectPopulation> lst_diff = new List<DefectPopulation>();
if (lst_codeDefectSrc.Count == lst_codeDefectDest.Count)
{
    if (lst_codeDefectSrc.Except(lst_codeDefectDest).ToList().Any()
            && lst_codeDefectDest.Except(lst_codeDefectSrc).ToList().Any())
    {
        status = false;
    }
    else
    {
        status = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, instead of doing `.Any()`, keep the lists so you can iterate over the items? Or do you want a position-based comparison?

Comment: Is this an ordered list or could the mismatch be independent of the position?

Comment: What is a mismatch? Is that where two items at a specific position are different? Do both `ClassCode` and `DefectCount` have to match? Is it where an item exists in one list but doesn't in the other? Are the instances of `DefectPopulation` in `lst_codeDefectSrc` the same as the ones in `lst_codeDefectDest`?

Comment: @JonasH, I want to keep the list and iterate over items

Comment: @Llama, both DefectCount and classcode should match

Comment: Take a look at how `.Except` works, you should provide your implementation for `IEqualityComparer<DefectPopulation` to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (lst_codeDefectSrc.Except(lst_codeDefectDest).ToList().Any()
        && lst_codeDefectDest.Except(lst_codeDefectSrc).ToList().Any())
...
```

To

```
var inSrcNotInDest = lst_codeDefectSrc.Except(lst_codeDefectDest).ToList();
var inDestNotInSrc = lst_codeDefectDest.Except(lst_codeDefectSrc).ToList();
if (inSrcNotInDest.Any() && inDestNotInSrc.Any()){
    // Use the respective list however you want
    lst_diff.AddRange(inSrcNotInDest);
    lst_diff.AddRange(inDestNotInSrc);
```

Note that the code above will use the default equality comparer, and that is reference comparison for class types. If you want value equality you should either write your own `IEqualityComparer<DefectPopulation>`, Implement `IEquatable<DefectPopulation>`, or change it to a struct, since that uses value equality per default.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieve in a following simple way.

If the intersection of two list has same number of elements as that of the lists that mean two lists are same.

You can use following code:

```
var commonItems = lst_codeDefectDest.Select(item => new { item.ClassCode, item.DefectCount })
                .Intersect(lst_codeDefectSrc.Select(item => new { item.ClassCode, item.DefectCount }));

status = commonItems.Count() == lst_codeDefectSrc.Count;
```

It is very well explained here :
https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/linq-intersect-method/